# React-native App fails to launch in Android with multiple warning messages on debug builds

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, react-native, npm

## Environment

react-native-cli: 2.0.1, node : v8.2.1, npm: 5.3.0,

Target Platform:
Android 5.0 x86-64 image

Development Operating System:
Windows 7 professional edition, x86_64

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
"axios": "^0.16.2",
"buffer": "^5.0.6",
"lodash": "^4.17.4",
"mobx": "^3.2.1",
"mobx-react": "^4.2.2",
"react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
"react-native": "0.45.1",
"react-native-background-timer": "^1.1.0",
"react-native-fetch-blob": "latest",
"react-native-timer": "^1.3.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
"babel-jest": "20.0.3",
"babel-preset-react-native": "2.0.0",
"jest": "20.0.4",
"react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
"tslint": "^5.4.3",
"typescript": "^2.4.1",
"typings": "^2.1.1"
},
```

## Steps to Reproduce

npm install, npm run build, react-native run-android

## Expected Behavior

This is supposed to launch the application successfully on Physical device connected via USB or on the emulator running.

## Actual Behavior

App fails to launch with these bunch of warning messages:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop 'alignItems' of value 'function checkType() {... [native code]
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop 'bacckgroundColor' supplied to 'SrollView': function colorPropType() { [native code] }
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop 'bacckgroundColor' supplied to 'View': function colorPropType() { [native code] }
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop 'display' of type 'function' supplied to 'RCTView', expected 'string'. Bad object:{} in RCTView (at View.js:128)
....
```

**Build and deployment works fine with release builds which means running the following command it works fine:
react-native run-android --variant=release**
2) ***The same code base doesn’t work with apk debug builds
react-native run-android --variant=debug***
3) The weird thing is that this behavior is not consistent. Intermittently sometimes it works fine. For example, I have tried using different combination of react/react-native versions in the package.json. Its observed that it worked once with react v0.47.1 and react-native v16.0.0-bet5. The same configuration on same set up failed later.
4) For once it also worked with a combination of both react/react-native upgraded to latest versions (v0.48_rc0 and v16.0.0-bet5 respectively). But that too is not consistently working.

Comment: Hi. I need some snippet of your code that you have wrote. May I?

Comment: @SatrioAdiPrabowo Thanks for your response. Unfortunately I am not allowed to share code here. But fortunately, this issue seems to be fixed with versions :  "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12" and "react-native": "0.47.0". I am no longer seeing this problem.